# javascript work out the size of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a mobile app and want to store the data on the device.

I am downloading and populating arrays then using local storage to save the data. The total amount of data is 20 categories and each category has 50 rows and each row would contain the HTML code of a page. So 20 X 50 X average number of chars on a page.

1. Is there a method to get the total size of the array that I have loaded back into the device. I can then 'guesstimate' how much I can store on the mobile device.
2. Are there any issues with using large arrays on mobile.

MrWarby

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that would have a great performance impact on a normal computer, and even more so for a mobile device. I suggest you try a different approach, like asynchronous loading of content (through API-calls) and populating static HTML-files. The static HTML-files would only be downloaded once and stored in a preferred way by the browser, so you don't have to waste local storage with HTML-pages as strings.

Comment: Hi @bvx89 the html pages are being produced using ckeditor so they are a static page. Can you elborate on 'stored in a preferred way' as I am not aware of any other way to store the data locally other than cookies or local storage. I suppose I may need to only store a small buffer of information so when the app starts there is some data present so the perceived startup time is less. ie they will see some data straight away while the rest is loaded in the background or just load the html pages on each click.

Comment: I should probably have been more clear, but yes, I meant that you should load the HTML-pages on each click. When a user clicks on a new subpage you should display a load animation/progressbar while fetching data async in JavaScript. When all the content has been fetched, load the HTML page and inject all data into it before discarding the load animation. By using load animations you increase the usability quality of your webpage so that the user doesn't think that it has stopped working.